# USB debugging Android 4.0.3 ICS: Eclipse does not see the device?

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, debugging, usb

I flashed my Samsung Galaxy S I9000 from Stock Android 2.3.6 ROM to Android 4.0.3 (Custom ROM by Team ICSSGS, because Samsung will not update the SGS to ICS).
So, everything went smooth and fine, except that Eclipse Indigo (Windows 7) does not the see the device when it is connected via USB debugging. However, usb mass storage does work.

So, IMHO, the issue could have 2 causes:

1. The Custom ROM is somewhat buggy.
2. Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7 does have a problem with USB debugging on Android 4.0.3. This might be true, as USB mass storage does work, so it seems the Windows driver and Android 4.0.3 seem to be OK

Does anybody have the same issue?
Does anybody know, if this issue appears in Eclipse Indigo / Linux, too?
Any solutions available?

Comment: do you have Samsung Kies installed???

Comment: I found the solution: As the ICSSGS Custom Rom is not based on any Samsung Stock Rom, it requires, instead of the Kies driver, the standard Google Android drivers. Installing the Google Android USB driver fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung requires proprietary drivers.

Check out:

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads

or just google "/my device name/ usb drivers"

Comment: see my comment above: the contrary is the case. tx anyway, ur hint got me on the right track :)

Answer (score 1):

Following an android system update (currently 4.0.3) my PC running on windows 7 64 bit confirmed driver recognition, but no samsung/PC connection was in fact active.
I'm no developper or geek....I don't follow the tech advice in some posts above...but I solved the problem thus:

I went into smartphone / settings /(under) data usage /”more” / (key in) USB utilities / message USB mass storage …”tap button (connect storage to PC) to copy files…computer and SD card”/result: window USB utilities…”connect USB cable…mass storage.”/ physical connection cable to PC / result:
Android icon (green)confirming USB connection with messg, “you have connected… touch button below…which is a pane featuring, “ Turn on USB storage”.Touch pane to activate. 
Android info messg “Turn off USB storage…if you turn on USB storage, some apps …may stop..unavailable..until turn off USB storage” 
Touch O.K button.
New window with Android icon (orange) confirming USB storage in use; smartphone explorer window pops up on PC. 
Important: Android messg warns you to “unmount” (correctly eject) USB storage (Android SD card is just like any other external HD to PC) which is done by right clicking on USB icon in task bar.
Note: if right clicking does not respond (as with my PC) go to, “My computer” / PC and eject your phone, in my case seen as drive (F), which I renamed, “smartphone”.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb start-server
```

Comment: I did kill the adb.exe process via the taskmanager on windows. No success. So, I did the equivalent of the above on a windows cmd prompt. Still, eclipse does not see the device. I dont have a linux installation now, but I would consider installing ubuntu and doing the testing on the SGS from ubuntu, if it is confirmed that the issue only appears on window boxes

Answer (score 0):

you did remember to enable the usb debugging , while not connected to the computer , right?
try to also disable it and connect the usb . it might have a bug related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest drivers(not for your phone) for (Samsung) phone which comes pre installed with Android ICS. This way probably the Sync manager still isn't going to work, but I got Eclipse detect my phone for debugging. HTC Desite Z with ICS, Drivers for HTC One)

Answer (score 0):

Right click to my computer -> properties -> device manager -> rigth click to unknown device -> update driver software -> browse for driver software on your computer -> point to: `path\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

just find usb driver from google which found on `eclipse path..\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`